# Which should be used for searching XGET or XPOST

Tags: elasticsearch

Which should be used (**XGET** or **XPOST**) for quering ElasticSearch.
Whether **XGET** or **XPOST** have faster response for searching.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments for GET:

- A search is conceptually a GET
- GET requests are typically optimized for caching, although this may be
- Some elasticsearch searches can be done as a GET request without requiring a request body

Arguments for POST:

- It's harder to perform a GET request with a request body because a lot of clients don't support it (including javascript XHR in modern browsers)
- GET requests are typically optimized for caching even when you don't want it (although there are many ways to prevent it such as adding a query string argument, such as `?time=1376535485`)
- People just don't expect a GET to have a request body ( see [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) )
- Caching requires an extra layer in front of elasticsearch (such as apache or nginx), although this may be a moot point since having an extra layer allows for gzip compression.

Personally, I prefer POST for simplicity's sake. Elasticsearch is already blazing fast and there's little need to cache requests beyond what elasticsearches already does internally unless you're dealing with a very high usage scenario.

Comment: I am facing one problem in that I am able to get highlighted in certain result but in certain result I am not is it due to XGET or XPOST or may be certain other reason.(This problem is with 2 character wildcard search)

Comment: Could you provide details or a link that explains the issue?

Comment: Perform wildcard search query with term --  *is*  -- and heighlight the result as well in attachment type. Perform 1 st with XPOST and XGET you will get different result with head plugin and  in certain cases highlighted field will not be shown.